# reference cell as sheet in criteria in countif formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a countif formula that gathers information from another sheet.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(test!A:A,{"Story","Task"},test!D:D,{"In Progress"}))
```

The sheet is named **test**.

Is there any way I can write test in another cell and reference it in the formula?

Eg: Cell **A3** = **test**

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A3!A:A,{"Story","Task"},A3!D:D,{"In Progress"}))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please check  [How to Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking). As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

The function to use is `INDIRECT`

So `A3`=`test` will be `=indirect("A"&"3")`
That is because INDIRECT returns the cell reference using the two parameters concatenated by `&`.

In your formula `A3` becomes the first parameter and `A:A` the second, resulting to:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS((indirect(A3&"!"&"A:A"),{"Story","Task"}, 
              (indirect(A3&"!"&"D:D"),{"In Progress"}))
```

You can read more [about INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en-GB).